# How to draw irregular shaped rectangle and fill out the color with four pin points in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, uiimageview, uiimage

I am currently developing application like "kresta app". First of all i picked image from photo gallery.then next my work is user can able to select the which area he want to apply blinds and shades. so what i want to do is i have four pins and user can able to touch and drag the pins for area selection. i implemented this logic with below code.

[image]jpg

In touches moved i called this method

```
 UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

// Set the starting point of the shape.
   [aPath moveToPoint:pinImageView1.center];
// Draw the lines.
[aPath addLineToPoint:pinImageView2.center];
[aPath addLineToPoint:pinImageView3.center];
[aPath addLineToPoint:pinImageView4.center];
[aPath closePath];

CAShapeLayer *square = [CAShapeLayer layer];
square.path = aPath.CGPath;
[pickedImageView.layer addSublayer:square];
```

my problem is each time it it add a layer. how to i implement this logic? is any way to remove previous layer and update new layer? or my way is wrong if wrong please suggest any other way to implement this logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save a reference to this `CAShapeLayer` in a class property, you can then simply update its `path` property again and again, and it will automatically update the sublayer on your view's layer. So, `addSublayer` once, and then in the future, just update the `path` for this `CAShapeLayer` anytime you want to reflect changes in the shape overlaying your image on screen.

Comment: @banu Your way is correct for the initial adding of the layer, though for subsequent updates, you'd just update the path, don't create a new `CAShapeLayer`. And I don't see where you specify the color of the fill (e.g. `square.fillColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.2] CGColor];`, or whatever), too.